# Hangfire recurring job never triggers?

Tags: c#, owin, hangfire

I expect the following code to execute `UpdateSearchIndex()`, yet it doesn't.  The `Start()` method is getting executed without a problem.  Nothing is written to my logs.

This is running in an IIS-hosted OWIN process.  What am I doing wrong?  Why doesn't `UpdateSearchIndex()` execute?

```
public static class ScheduleUpdates
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .UseNLogLogProvider()
            .UseMemoryStorage();

        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("update-search-idx", () => UpdateSearchIndex(), Cron.Minutely);
        RecurringJob.Trigger("update-search-idx");
    }

    public static void UpdateSearchIndex()
    {
        Debugger.Break();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like youre not starting Hangfire. In your Owin startup class you should call UseHangfireServer() extension method on IAppBuilder (http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/quick-start.html)